# Table spanning multiple pages with another embedeed table that can span two pages

Tags: tables, longtable, embedding

I have found out that longtabu inside longtabu is not possible but maybe another solution exists. I am autogenerating lots of latex code for documenting a certain binary communication protocol and I need tables to span across pages that have embedded another table which can in itself span across at most two pages. Code below is not pretty but it compiles with TexLive and TexLive extra fonts (for LY1). Any advice how to achieve that would be welcome.
My

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Add bold and italic
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable} % also needed by longtabu
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\hspace{-0.6cm}\begin{longtabu}{| l | l | l | X | l | l |}
\firsthline
\textbf{Id} & 20 & \textbf{Name}: &Settings & \textbf{Data Size}: & 26 bytes\\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.97\textwidth}
    \textbf{Description}: This packet is being sent ..ehehe
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}
} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{ \textbf{Fields:} } \\
\multicolumn{6}{ | l |}{

% I would like to have another longtable here .. the nested table does not break across pages
    \begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{ | l | l | X |}
\firsthline
\textbf{Bits} & \textbf{Field Name} & \textbf{Description}\\
\hline
0 : 2 & SETTING\_A & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 
    \textbf{Values}:\\0 - MODE\_A \\ \textit{Comment A.}\\1 - MODE\_B\\\textit{Comment B . dsdsjkhdsakjahsasd}\\2 - MODE\_C\\\textit{Comment C. asdsadasfsddssd}\\3 - MODE\_D\\\textit{Comment D. fdassdaskjdhasd}\\4 - MODE\_E\\\textit{Comment E. fdjksfdsjhgffhjjjhsfd}\\5 - MODE\_F\\\textit{Comment F}\\6 - MODE\_G\\\textit{Comment E}\\\vspace{-0.27cm}

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
3 : 7 & SETTING\_B & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
8 : 10 & SETTING\_C & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
11 : 13 & SETTING\_D & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
14 : 16 & SETTING\_E & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 
    \textbf{Values}:\\0 - PH\_A\\\textit{Aomment A}\\1 - PH\_B\\\textit{Comment B}\\2 - PH\_C\\\textit{Comment C dsasdjka hsdkjah dsakjsadh kjdash ksaj}\\3 - PH\_D\\\textit{Comment D fdsfdsfdsf sdsdfds}\\4 - PH\_E\\\textit{Comment E asdkhdaskjdshjsakhasdkjds}\\5 - PH\_F\\\textit{Comment F. dsajashsaddsasfdfsddsf}\\\vspace{-0.27cm}

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
17 : 29 & SETTING\_F & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
30 : 42 & SETTING\_G & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
43 : 48 & SETTING\_H & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
49 : 54 & SETTING\_I & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
55 : 61 & SETTING\_J & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
62 : 77 & SETTING\_K & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
78 : 93 & SETTING\_L & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
94 : 109 & SETTING\_M & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \\\hline
110 : 125 & SETTING\_N & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
126 : 141 & SETTING\_L & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
142 : 150 & PULSE\_WIDTH & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
151 : 159 & PULSE\_WIDTH\_HIGH & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
160 : 175 & DELAY & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
176 : 188 & TOTAL\_PROGRAM\_TIME & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
189 : 201 & TOTAL\_PHASE\_TIME & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \lasthline
\end{tabularx}
} \\
\lasthline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make any parts that need to break be part of the outer table, something like this

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Add bold and italic
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable} % also needed by longtabu
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\hspace{-0.6cm}

\begin{longtabu}{ | l | l | X |}
\firsthline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l | l | l | X | l | l }
\textbf{Id} & 20 & \textbf{Name}: &Settings & \textbf{Data Size}: & 26 bytes\\
\end{tabularx}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.97\textwidth}
    \textbf{Description}: This packet is being sent ..ehehe
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}
} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ \textbf{Fields:} } \\


\firsthline
\textbf{Bits} & \textbf{Field Name} & \textbf{Description}\\
\hline
0 : 2 & SETTING\_A & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 
    \textbf{Values}:\\0 - MODE\_A \\ \textit{Comment A.}\\1 - MODE\_B\\\textit{Comment B . dsdsjkhdsakjahsasd}\\2 - MODE\_C\\\textit{Comment C. asdsadasfsddssd}\\3 - MODE\_D\\\textit{Comment D. fdassdaskjdhasd}\\4 - MODE\_E\\\textit{Comment E. fdjksfdsjhgffhjjjhsfd}\\5 - MODE\_F\\\textit{Comment F}\\6 - MODE\_G\\\textit{Comment E}\\\vspace{-0.27cm}

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
3 : 7 & SETTING\_B & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
8 : 10 & SETTING\_C & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
11 : 13 & SETTING\_D & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
14 : 16 & SETTING\_E & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 
    \textbf{Values}:\\0 - PH\_A\\\textit{Aomment A}\\1 - PH\_B\\\textit{Comment B}\\2 - PH\_C\\\textit{Comment C dsasdjka hsdkjah dsakjsadh kjdash ksaj}\\3 - PH\_D\\\textit{Comment D fdsfdsfdsf sdsdfds}\\4 - PH\_E\\\textit{Comment E asdkhdaskjdshjsakhasdkjds}\\5 - PH\_F\\\textit{Comment F. dsajashsaddsasfdfsddsf}\\\vspace{-0.27cm}

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
17 : 29 & SETTING\_F & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
30 : 42 & SETTING\_G & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
43 : 48 & SETTING\_H & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
49 : 54 & SETTING\_I & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
55 : 61 & SETTING\_J & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
62 : 77 & SETTING\_K & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
78 : 93 & SETTING\_L & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
94 : 109 & SETTING\_M & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \\\hline
110 : 125 & SETTING\_N & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
126 : 141 & SETTING\_L & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
142 : 150 & PULSE\_WIDTH & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
151 : 159 & PULSE\_WIDTH\_HIGH & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
160 : 175 & DELAY & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
176 : 188 & TOTAL\_PROGRAM\_TIME & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}
    \tabularnewline \hline
189 : 201 & TOTAL\_PHASE\_TIME & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth} 

    \end{minipage}\\
    \tabularnewline
\lasthline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A bit changes layout and I had to change one \firsthline to \hline to remove spacing but it works in this particular case! Thank you! Still interesting if it is possible with the previous layout (the table visibly being inside the other table)

Comment: you can add vertical spacing etc to make it look like anything but a table cell is basically a box so it's like putting something inside `\mbox` and so will never break unless you deconstruct the entire table.

Comment: Interesting. I will play with it. Much appreciated.