# minipage inside long table gives extra new line

Tags: pdftex, longtable, enumerate, itemize, minipage

I defined a new environments to add top and bottom padding to a minipage and to be used inside a lone table cell (I have used \linewidth to specify the width of the minipage in the new environment). But it gives an extra newline for the following enumeration. see the row 2 of the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{book}

%tweek font spacing for better look
\usepackage{microtype}

%enable linespacing commands%
\usepackage{setspace}

%enable H option that prevent figure floats
\usepackage{float}

%used to import graphics%
\usepackage{graphicx}

%used for referencing%
\usepackage{harvard}

%customise chapter styles%
\usepackage{titlesec}

%set margins%
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

%allows to create tables with different column widths%
\usepackage{tabularx}

%allows to create tables that can span across pages%
\usepackage{longtable}%dependency of longtabu (bug fix patch applied)
\usepackage{tabu}%contains longtabu

%enable support for source code
%this package needs the python package 'sudo pip install pygments'
%add pdfLaTeX option -shell-escape
\usepackage{minted}

%enables itemize space customization options
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{stablecell}{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\vspace{2mm}
}{
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}
}

\newenvironment{spackenum}{
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
}{
\vspace{1mm}
\end{enumerate} 
}

\newenvironment{spackitems}{
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
}{
\vspace{1mm}
\end{itemize} 
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%keep only the page number%
\pagestyle{plain}

%set onehalf line spacing
\onehalfspacing

%customise chapter styles from titlesec%
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}

%set bibliography listing style to agsm%
\bibliographystyle{agsm}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table Start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1 , l ]  X[4.1 , l ] }
\caption{xxxxxxxx}\label{table:xxxxxx}\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Heading Start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hline
\endfirsthead
%==============================================
%Next page headings
\hline
\endhead
%==============================================
%Before page break text
\endfoot
%==============================================
\hline
\endlastfoot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Heading End %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\hline
\textbf{what i want}
& \begin{stablecell}
\begin{spackenum}
\item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxx
\item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxx
\end{spackenum} 
\end{stablecell}\\
%==============================================
\hline
\textbf{without minipage}
&\begin{spackenum}
\item xx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
\item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
\end{spackenum} \\
%==============================================
\hline
\textbf{extra line}
& \begin{stablecell}
\begin{spackenum}
\item xx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
\item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
\end{spackenum} 
\end{stablecell}\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Body End %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{longtabu}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table End %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using minipage at all here? It can't do anything useful. What is the intention, then we could suggest an alternative markup

Comment: intention of using minipage was to remove the bottom space left by the list even after setting [noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]. and create a reusable element that can be used in table cells with any content inside with a consistent top and bottom padding

Comment: what I want to do is to create the rows as in the first row of the image.

Comment: sure but an X column is already a p-column which is more or less an identical implementation to \parbox and minipage, why the extra minipage box?

Comment: thanx for the info about X column. But I updated the code and image to show what happens without the minipage.

Comment: Check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48007/table-spanning-multiple-pages-with-another-embedeed-table-that-can-span-two-page

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by your placement of the `\vspace` commands relative to the end of the environments.  Placing them *after* the environments gives the intended spacing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{stablecell}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\vspace{2mm}
}{\end{minipage}\vspace{1mm}}

\newenvironment{spackenum}{%
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
}{\end{enumerate}\vspace{1mm}}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1 , l ] X[4.1 , l ] }
  \caption{xxxxxxxx}\label{table:xxxxxx}\\
  \hline \endfirsthead \hline \endhead \endfoot \hline \endlastfoot
  \textbf{what i want} & \begin{stablecell}
    \begin{spackenum}
    \item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxx
    \item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxx
    \end{spackenum}
  \end{stablecell}\\
  \hline \textbf{without minipage} &\begin{spackenum}
  \item xx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
  \item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
  \end{spackenum} \\
  \hline \textbf{no extra line} & \begin{stablecell}
    \begin{spackenum}
    \item xx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx.
    \item xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxx.
    \end{spackenum}
  \end{stablecell}\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

In general, it may be better to use `\addvspace`, which will ensure a minimum amount of space but will not accumulate successive vertical spaces.